# How to subtract / add a day to date

Tags: scala, date

I am trying to get today's date and find the List of dates for the previous 5 days in SCALA. 
For example, I have to subtract 3 days from the current date and add that resultant date to a List.

How can I do that?

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
val dateFormatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
var today_date = new  java.util.Date()
var today = dateFormatter.format(today_date) 

var lst_5_days = ArrayBuffer[String]()
for(i <- 1 to 5)
{
  val prev_day= /* method to get`enter code here` date for previous day 
                 (today - i days) */
  lst_5_days +=prev_day
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use `java.util.Date` nor `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` since when Java 8 was released they were replaced with newer, easier to use and immutable alternatives: `java.time.LocalDate` and `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`.

For example, `LocalDate` has a very convenient method `minusDays`, which you could use:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val now = LocalDate.now()
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")

val last5Days = (1 to 5).map(i => formatter.format(now.minusDays(i)))
```